# How to call root file directly in magento2- i don't want to create class?

Tags: magento2

I have upload.php file in magento2 root folder.

How can i access directly `www.example.com/upload.php` directly in magento2?

Comment: want to include this file from another file or your  want to call this url

Comment: I want to call directly form magento2 root folder

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: I want my custom script there for perform custom functionality

Comment: have you tried with a die in the end of file?

Comment: It's not possible by core php ? @MurtuzaZabuawala
I don't want to create class

Comment: @RutveeSojitra if you are using magento root from pub then put `upload.php` in pub folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `upload.php` file in your magento root folder

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
echo $baseUrl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(); 
?>
```

Comment: Not working !!! ithink it's need any htaccess rule

Comment: NO htacsess needed for script, it's custom script i'm using. May be your store not configured well http://prntscr.com/k1jbfe

Answer (score 0):

The **root** of Magento 2 is `http/pub/`.

So if you upload you file there, you should be able to access it via www.example.com/upload.php

If you want to keep the file in `/http/` directory and still access it, you can do it in NginX (if you use NginX). Something like this would do the trick:

```
# upload.php
location = /upload.php {
    alias /full/path/to/your/magentoproject/http/upload.php;
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE** execution of PHP files might be restricted when trying to access the file inside of the pub directory. If you want to execute the file from inside the PUB directory, try adding something like this:

```
   location ~* \.(php) {
     include fastcgi_params;
   }
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are using Apache, try following:

```
alias "/upload.php" "/full/path/to/your/magentoproject/http/upload.php"
```

And reload your Apache services.

Comment: Not working !!! have tried

Comment: Are you using Apache or NginX?

Comment: apache   @Bare Feet

Comment: Updated the answer.